# Getting axios error while trying to make request to external API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

This is the error: it seems like the error is in axios request, but i'm not sure..
Strange, because when i test the request in Postmen, i'm getting clean and beautiful response.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\lusyv\OneDrive\Documents\Elevation\projects\weatherApp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\lusyv\OneDrive\Documents\Elevation\projects\weatherApp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\lusyv\OneDrive\Documents\Elevation\projects\weatherApp\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:244:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:13644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13644) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

I'm trying to render weather data from external API through localhost server and get this error while clicking on "search button"
This is the simple MVC architecture, here is my code:

server.js

```
router.get(`/city/:cityName`, async (req, res) => {
    let cityName = req.params.cityName
    console.log("LU")
    const response = await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&units=metric&appid=ec035401d1d40d6f5bb07d9588812996`)

    let city = {
        name: response.data.name,
        temprature: response.data.main.temp,
        condition: response.data.weather[0].description,
        conditionPic: response.data.weather[0].icon,  //http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}@2x.png
        wind: response.data.wind.speed           
    }
    
    res.send(city)
})
```

model.js

```
class TempManager {
    constructor(){
        this.cityData = []
    }

    async getDataFromDB(){
        let citiesData = await $.get(`/cities`)

        if(citiesData){
           this.cityData = citiesData
        }

        return(this.cityData)
    }

    async getCityDataFromExtAPI(cityName){
        let city = await $.get(`/city/:${cityName}`)
        console.log(city)
        this.cityData.push(city)

        return(this.cityData)
    }
}
```

controller.js

```
let manager = new TempManager()
let renderer = new Renderer()

const loadPage = async () => {
    let citiesDataFromDB = await manager.getDataFromDB()
    renderer.renderData(citiesDataFromDB)
}

const handleSearch = async (userInput) => {
    console.log(userInput)
    let city = await manager.getCityDataFromExtAPI(userInput)
    console.log(city)
    renderer.renderData(city)
}
$(`#search-btn`).on("click", async function () {
    let userInput = $(`#city-input`).val()
    await handleSearch(userInput)
})
```

render.js

```
class Renderer {
    constructor(){}

    renderData(allCityData){
        const source = $('#first-template').html()
        const template = Handlebars.compile(source)
        const newHTML = template({city: allCityData})
        $("#city").empty()
        $('#city').append(newHTML)
    }
}
```

index.html

```
</head>

    <input type="text" id="city-input">
    <button id="search-btn">Search</button>

<script id="first-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   
    {{#each allCityData}}
    <div id="city">
        <p id="name">{{this.name}}</p>
        <p id="temprature">{{this.temprature}}</p>
        <p id="conditions">{{this.conditions}}</p>
        <img src="{{this.conditionPic}}" alt="condition.jpg" id="image">
        <p id="wind">{{this.wind}}</p>
        <button id="save-btn">Save</button>
        <button id="remove-btn">Remove</button>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
  
  </script>
<body>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: An [http 404 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) means "Not found". Start by debugging the url actually used. As for the unhandled promise rejection that requires a try/catch when using `await`.

Comment: Thank you! After additing try/catck, promise rejection disapeared, but i'm still getting error 404. I use Postman to test a get request and getting the response: ``` {
    "name": "London",
    "temprature": 24.23,
    "condition": "clear sky",
    "conditionPic": "01d",
    "wind": 4.6
}```
on http://localhost:3000/city/london

Comment: I just tried in node.js this request `axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&units=metric&appid=ec035401d1d40d6f5bb07d9588812996')` and it works just fine

Comment: So something is different for the failed one. Colon in `$.get(`/city/:${cityName}`)` looks very suspicious and is likely showing up in `req.params.cityName`

Comment: :))))) colon was redundant! Love stackoverflow and it's users.